# Como filtrar o logcat por linha de comando?

Tags: android, debug, logcat

Estava lendo a [documentação do android](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat.html?hl=pt-br) e vi que é possível monitorar o logcat por linha de comando, sem necessariamente estar com a IDE aberta.

Instalei uma versão minimalista do ADB(somente o necessário para ele funcionar em linha de comando) e estou tentando monitorar erros de aplicativos do meu celular, para facilitar a leitura, exporto para um arquivo de texto no prompt de comando, utilizando o comando abaixo:

```
adb logcat >> C:\\Temp\logcat.txt
```

Este comando já atende ao meu proposito, porém ele registra tudo que ocorre no celular, e gostaria de que fosse registrado apenas erros, e se for possivel filtrar isso, de aplicativos em execução.

Há alguma maneira de efetuar um desses filtros ou os dois por linha de comando?
Eu não estou sabendo aplicar as tags de privacidade na linha de comando.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

É possível filtrar a saída do *logcat* por *tag* e nível de prioridade.

Uma entrada no logcat é registada através da chamada a um dos métodos da classe Log. O método chamado define o nível de prioridade(`Log.i()`, `Log.e()`, etc) sendo a tag definida pela string passada ao primeiro parâmetro:

```
Log.i("MyActivity","Passei no onCreate");
```

A expressão de filtragem tem o formato `tag:priority`, onde `tag` é a *tag* das entradas que queremos listar e `priority` é o nível mínimo de prioridade **mínima** a ser listado.
Pode usar mais de uma expressão de filtragem, separando-as por espaços.

O comando para listar as entradas com a *tag* **MyActivity** e nível de prioridade *info* ou superior é:

```
adb logcat MyActivity:I *:S
```

`*:S` evita que qualquer outra *tag* seja listada.

Para informação mais completa ver [Como filtrar a saída do registro](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat.html?hl=pt-br#filteringOutput) na documentação.

Comment: para o usuarios linux tambem pode se usar o pipe, algo tipo `$ adb logcat | grep "MyActivity"` que funfa blzura

Comment: Isso se eu estiver depurando um app em especifico, no caso, eu queria apurar dos apps em execução no meu aparelho, ai não tem como eu saber as Activities deles. Não tem como filtrar isso?

Comment: Por aquilo que vi na documentação, não. Apenas por *tag* e nível de prioridade. Até porque o nome da aplicação ou da Activity não existem no log. Pode ignorar a tag usando `*`, por exemplo listar todas as entradas com nível de prioridade "erro" ou superior: `adb logcat *:E`

Comment: Consegui utlizando o comando `adb logcat ActivityManager:I *:S >> C:\\Temp\logcat.txt `